# snd-soc-dummy as sound card for embedded linux

Tags: linux, audio, kernel, linux-device-driver, alsa

I want to use ALSA *simple-audio-card* witch *snd-soc-dummy* to play and record sound from I2S/PCM interface, based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47398505/register-snd-soc-dummy-in-a-device-tree) and [this patch](https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/7679391/) I succeeded to play out audio, but audio capturing still not works.

Using command:

```
arecord -vvv -f dat /dev/null
```

Shows there is no incoming sound samples, but logic analyzer shows something else, there is coming in data, and I don't know why *arecord* can not read that.

My device tree for sound device:

```
&i2s0 {
    status = "okay";
    pinctrl-0 = <&i2s0_pins>;
    pinctrl-names = "default";
    #sound-dai-cells = <0>;
};

/ {
    codec_dummy: codec_dummy {
        compatible = "linux,snd-soc-dummy";
        #sound-dai-cells = <0>;
        status = "okay";
    };

    sound {
        compatible = "simple-audio-card";
        simple-audio-card,name = "DUMMY_SND";

        simple-audio-card,format = "dsp_a";
        simple-audio-card,bitclock-master = <&snd_cpu>;
        simple-audio-card,frame-master = <&snd_cpu>;
        simple-audio-card,mclk-fs = <512>;
        status = "okay";

        snd_cpu: simple-audio-card,cpu {
            sound-dai = <&i2s0>;
            dai-tdm-slot-num = <2>;
            dai-tdm-slot-width = <16>;
        };

        snd_codec: simple-audio-card,codec {
            sound-dai = <&codec_dummy>;
        };
    };
};
```

And my */etc/asound.conf* file:

```
pcm.device{
        format S16_LE
        rate 44100
        type hw
        card 0
        channels 2
}

pcm.!default{
    type plug
    slave.pcm "device"
}
```

Maybe you know how to fix audio capturing in this case?